# External onLoad function does not trigger in script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am struggling to make the following component to work as expected :

```
const Example=()=>{
    const ref = useRef(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        let refValue;   

        if (ref.current) {
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "https://externalsource.com/hey.js";

            script.async = true;
            script.type = "text/javascript";

            const onScriptLoad=()=>{
                 externalFunction();
               };

            script.onload = onScriptLoad;
            ref.current.appendChild(script);
            refValue = ref.current;
        };

        return () => {
            if (refValue) {
                while (refValue.firstChild) {
                    refValue.removeChild(refValue.firstChild);
                };
            };
        };
    }, [ref,]);


    return (
        <div className="..." >
            <div ref={ref} className="..."  />
        </div>
    );

};
```

In React , I always get "externalFunction is not defined" , whereas in NextJS the component does work as expected. Could you please let me know why , and how would you address it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Since React runs on top of NextJS, it's hard to know what this means: "in NextJS the component does work as expected".  In general, you need to import things for use.

Comment: @jmargolisvt What I mean by that is that I don't get any errors and that the externalFunction runs properly . I am especially confused by this, given that Next runs on top of React...